# Login cakephp is not working I dont have (admin) table instead of (user)

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.4

Hello I am new to cakephp
My problem is the `$this->Auth->login($this->request->data)` is always returning true, I don't know if it has something to do with the table name, my table name is "admins" not "users", it is accepting any password, something is really wrong.

here is my login function:

```
public function login()
    {
        $this->layout = 'login';
        if ($this->request->is('post')) 
        {

            if ($this->Auth->login()) 
            {
                return $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirect());
            }
            else 
            {
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('Username or password is incorrect'));
            }
        }
    }
```

I took that function as is from [here](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/authentication.html#identifying-users-and-logging-them-in) this is not logging in **at all**

my old code was:

```
public function login()
    {
        $this->layout = 'login';            
        if(!$this->Session->read('Auth.User'))
        {
            debug($this->Session->read('Auth.User'));
            if ($this->request->is('post')) 
            {
                debug($this->Auth->login());
                //$this->pa($this->request->data);

                if ($this->Auth->login()) 
                {
                    $this->Admin->id = $this->Session->read('Auth.Admin.id');
                    $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirect());
                } 
                else 
                {                    
                    $this->Session->setFlash(__('Username or password is incorrect'));
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirect());
        }
    }
```

its not working too

Comment: Please mention your exact CakePHP version, tag your question accordingly, and depending on the version used read **http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/authentication.html#identifying-users-and-logging-them-in**

Comment: my cakephp version is : 2.4.4

Comment: only use
$this->Auth->login();
Its auto authenticate

Comment: Can you add some code which you have done so far?

Comment: There's a little about this question that's not the same as the other, but it's obvious you haven't done any research yet, as the part you've specified as the issue (always returning true) is specifically mentioned in the CakePHP book.

Comment: @ndm I took their code as is, now its not logging in at all

Comment: There's nothing I can do from here - do some debugging. If you can't solve the problem, open a new question with the necessary details (your login action code, your auth component configuration, your login view form, your table schema, etc), what you've tried so far to solve the problem, etc...

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your Auth model. Add this to your controller and try.

```
function beforeFilter() {
  $this->Auth->userModel = 'admins';
}
```

also if you have different fields other than username and password, you need to pass them as well to Auth something like this

```
   $this->Auth->fields = array(
        'username' => 'your_username_field',
        'password' => 'your_password_field'
    );
```

Hope this will help

Comment: add that line "$this->Auth->userModel = 'admins';" in which controller

Comment: `$this->Auth->fields = array(
                        'username' => $this->request->data['Admin']['username'],
                        'password' => $this->request->data['Admin']['password']
                    );`